# How to solve cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content error in .taglib.xml file Macbook M1

Tags: eclipse, macos, maven

I tried to update the maven project, but got an error in .taglib.xml file. In windows computer this error does not appear, but it was happened in my macbook. Please see as below.

[image]

[image]

This code in taglib.xml file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
                version="2.0">
    
    <namespace>http://primefaces.org/babylon</namespace>
    
    <tag>
        <description><![CDATA[Menu is a navigation component for Babylon Layout.]]></description>
        <tag-name>menu</tag-name>
        <component>
            <component-type>org.primefaces.component.BabylonMenu</component-type>
            <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.BabylonMenuRenderer</renderer-type>
        </component>
        <attribute>
            <description><![CDATA[Unique identifier of the component in a namingContainer.]]></description>
            <name>id</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <type>java.lang.String</type>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <description><![CDATA[Boolean value to specify the rendering of the component, when set to false component will not be rendered.]]></description>
            <name>rendered</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <type>java.lang.Boolean</type>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <description><![CDATA[An el expression referring to a server side UIComponent instance in a backing bean.]]></description>
            <name>binding</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <type>javax.faces.component.UIComponent</type>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <description><![CDATA[Name of the client side widget.]]></description>
            <name>widgetVar</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <type>java.lang.String</type>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <description><![CDATA[A menu model instance to create menu programmatically.]]></description>
            <name>model</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <type>org.primefaces.model.menu.MenuModel</type>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <description><![CDATA[Inline style of the main container element.]]></description>
            <name>style</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <type>java.lang.String</type>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <description><![CDATA[Style class of the main container element.]]></description>
            <name>styleClass</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <type>java.lang.String</type>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <description><![CDATA[Whether the orientation of the menu is horizontal.]]></description>
            <name>horizontal</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <type>java.lang.Boolean</type>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <description><![CDATA[When enabled, scroll state is saved in a cookie for the session. Default is true.]]></description>
            <name>statefulScroll</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <type>java.lang.Boolean</type>
            <defaultValue>true</defaultValue>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

I'm not sure the library from dependencies in pom.xml of parent project are not added in child project or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find that `defaultValue` is not allowed there. I'm not sure it's at all declared. If you hover over the "attribute" tag's name, the hover info will show what is legal there. You'll have to remove it, and when you want `statefulScroll` to be `true`, set it as such.

Comment: Thank you for your informaition. I just know the real problem is after I build the project by mvn update, clean and install but some resources in directory path of maven resouces plugin at  pom.xml are not build in target folder, so some libraries have not yet and taglib.xml cannot call them.